# Joint use of floor and sqrt in Haskell

Tags: haskell, sqrt, floor

I want my function to read in an integer and return the square root rounded down to the nearest integer. This is what I've tried:

```
roundSqrt :: Int -> Int
roundSqrt x = floor (sqrt x)
```

The error I get is, "Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of -sqrt'", but I don't understand what this means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of sqrt is:

```
λ> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

The type of floor is:

```
λ> ::t floor
floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

So, `sqrt` needs a type which has a `Floating` constraint. You can use the `fromIntegral` function to achieve that:

```
roundSqrt :: Int -> Int
roundSqrt x = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral x))
```

Comment: Then you get rid of the boilerplate by using the composition operator: `roundSqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral`.